# How to point website to another?

Tags: web, web-hosting

My school offers free hosting on their servers, but it appears as a site under their directory -- for example, cs.swarthmore.edu/my_name. I would like to use the hosting, but I want the site url to be of one of my domains. Is that possible or should I shell out for hosting?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that hosting for hosting any of your domains because that hosting is just for their domains or for a particular directory. You just can do one thing if you don't have to pay for hosting which is you can iFrame or redirect visitors from you domain to your school's site. So that the visitors can just visit your site and get the data from your school's server.